# Ignoring return value of function declared with "warn_unused_result" attribute

Tags: objective-c, xcode8

We start having this warning on all the `becomeFirstResponder` function call in our Objective-C code.

> Ignoring return value of function declared with "warn_unused_result" attribute

```
[self.phoneNumberField becomeFirstResponder]; // warning here!!!
```

What's the best way to suppress this warning here?

---

Edit: I also tried this,

```
BOOL ignore = [self.emailField becomeFirstResponder];
```

But with that, Xcode has warning about the variable `ignore` is not used :(

---

I also tried this,

```
BOOL ignore = [self.phoneNumberField becomeFirstResponder];
if (ignore) {

}
```

The warnings is gone in this case. But I don't think I can even past my own code review. It is too ugly!

Comment: Never add code as image. Make it text.

Comment: You could actually check the return value and do something if it returns `NO`.

Comment: @AminNegm-Awad thanks for pointing that out. I've updated it to text instead of image.

Answer (score 58, accepted):

It should work to cast the expression to a void expression.

```
(void)[self.emailField becomeFirstResponder];
```

(Even I cannot reproduce the warning. However, this might depend on the warning flags.)

To your edit:

```
BOOL ignore = [self.emailField becomeFirstResponder];
```

Likely

```
BOOL ignore = [self.emailField becomeFirstResponder]; 
ignore = ignore;
// or
(void)ignore;
```

should remove the warning. (It does with my flags.) However, this an ugly hack, too.

BTW: There is a reason for the attribute. Maybe you should recheck, whether it is a good idea, not to test for the return value.

Comment: what's the reason of this warning? do you any idea?

Comment: Because the method is decorated with `warn_unused_result`, what means, that the compiler should warn, if the result is unused.

Comment: (void)[self.emailField becomeFirstResponder];  works like a charm!

Answer (score 13):

You could get this warning if you have a Swift function that you call from Objective-C code. You can silence it by adding `@discardableResult` before the function in Swift, like this:

```
@objc @discardableResult func yourFanzyFuncInSwift(argument: String) -> Bool { ... }
```

Seems like *warn_unused_result* is the default setting in Swift, meaning that you shouldn't write code that ignores return values.

Comment: Just a note that you unfortunately cannot add @discardableresult to an init(), so when calling it to create a shared instance singleton, but not using it at that time (you want the set-up initialization side effects) you get this warning.

Comment: @chadbag I believe the message from Apple it’s quite clear here - you shouldn’t init an object and then ignore it. I bet it’s way to refactor your code so this can be avoided.

Comment: If you have a singleton and need a side effect when it first is run to happen only for the side effect, for example, requesting permissions of various Apple services, you can either declare a variable and return it and then never use that variable, or you can ignore the return value.  Casting it to (void) works nicely.

Comment: This solution has the advantage of not having to sprinkle (void) at every callsite.

Answer (score 0):

less charm to use **Associated Objects**

- code part:

```
    #import "objc/runtime.h"
    #import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
    
    @interface NSObject(Helper)
    @property (nonatomic, assign) BOOL nonsense;
    @end
    
    @implementation NSObject(Helper)
    
    - (void)setNonsense:(BOOL)val{
        NSNumber *obj = [NSNumber numberWithBool: val];
        objc_setAssociatedObject(self, @selector(nonsense), obj, OBJC_ASSOCIATION_RETAIN_NONATOMIC);
    }
    
    - (BOOL)nonsense{
        NSNumber *obj = objc_getAssociatedObject(self, @selector(nonsense));
        return obj.boolValue;
    }
    
    @end
```

- usage part:

```
    self.nonsense = [self.sessionInputView endEditing:YES];
```